# Laravel Sanctum - CSRF token mismatch al enviar petición POST con Angular

Tags: laravel, angular, cabeceras-http, auth, laravel-sanctum

Tengo una API en Laravel y una aplicación web en Angular que debe consumir de dicha API, el problema que tengo es que estoy implementando la autenticación mediante [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum#spa-authentication) y tengo el siguiente error al intentar enviar una solicitud POST para el inicio de sesión:

> {message: "CSRF token mismatch.", exception:
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException",…} POST
>   http://xxxxxxxx.test/login 419 (unknown status)

En mi código primero hago una petición `GET` a `http://xxxxxxx.test/sanctum/csrf-cookie` que es la ruta de Sanctum donde la API establece una cookie de sesión (`laravel_session`) y otra del CSRF (`XSRF-TOKEN`) y luego si que hago la petición POST al `/login`.

El problema es que según la documentación, el token debe ser retornado en la petición POST en una cabecera `X-XSRF-TOKEN` y según la documentación, Angular debería hacerlo por sí solo, pero revisando los Request-Headers desde el inspector de Chrome, no aparece que esta cabecera haya sido enviada. Entonces, he pensado en reenviarla yo mismo, pero no tengo forma de obtenerla, ya que solo recibo esto:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Fri, 29 May 2020 15:16:13 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.35 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.6
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.6
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://app.xxxxxx.test:4200
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImRjNzZmckxHR2xWY05uUHdKR3QxR0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiNnZkUjJRSWVKNTViaEpoTGpHdHNLNmloYlBTaVAycmNiek5Hck41OFI2a052S094NVFFMlRxekxiMG8zQTV3MiIsIm1hYyI6IjVjYWQzYmMwNTBhNDYwMTBhNGMwNTg3ODBjNTNiNGYwNzk1NGNlNTMzMDBiYjAxZjQwNmQ2ZTIzYzgwYjI5YTMifQ%3D%3D; expires=Fri, 29-May-2020 17:16:13 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=.xxxxxx.test; samesite=lax
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImdrbjBwRlhJR1ZiVHpOdFQxTDBRUkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibjFWUng3MVhWZXAzM1l0V3VSWE04dGJ4eFZ4SXh5SXNEUGtnaFJDT2NTNnNnbzJOQXRKa3grQ1pzOVhOZ3oyNyIsIm1hYyI6IjRhMzhiMGRmNzYzODdjYjdiMjI5Yjc2MTY2ZmE1YTkzMDA2NjczMzViZGE0ZGU1MDI3ZjFlNzg5MjJlZDA5YWMifQ%3D%3D; expires=Fri, 29-May-2020 17:16:13 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=.xxxxxx.test; httponly; samesite=lax
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

En cuanto a los demás ajustes estoy casi seguro de que están bien, y en cuanto a los dominios, Laravel está en `http://miweb.test:80` y Angular en `http://app.miweb.test:4200`

Comment: ¿Cómo estás recuperando y guardando los token que te devuelve la API? Podrías poner más detalle del componente del login de Angular. Según creo (muy por encima porque no he visto tu código), deberías tomar los token y enviarlos a la API en cada solicitud que haces desde Angular. Esto lo puedes llevar a cabo con un interceptor. Favor comenta esos detalles. Saludos.

Comment: No lo hago porque supuestamente debe hacerlo angular por sí solo, pero he visto que solo lo hace por nosotros cuando la URL de la solicitud es relativo y no absoluto, cosa que es imposible en mi caso dado que cada proyecto está en un subdominio diferente. Entonoces, no lo hago yo porque no sé como interceptar la cabecera Set-Cookie del token. Gracias

Comment: No sé como lo estás haciendo en tu código, pero en Angular, cuando quiero capturar datos de la cabecera lo hago de la siguiente manera: ```this._http.post(API_URL, DATA, {observe: 'response'});```. Luego, cuando llamas a ese método y te subscribes puedes acceder a la data de response, donde tienes parámetros del header. Me comentas como te va. Saludos

Comment: Sí, pero en este caso Laravel no devuelve el token como respuesta, sino que lo devuelve en una cabecera (como muestro en el ejemplo de la respuesta) y esa cabecera es inaccesible. No he resuelto el problema pero he pasado a usar otro método, muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Sólo para no quedarme con la duda. Cuando te subscribes al método (haciendo el observe: 'response'), ¿no puedes acceder al la data tipo ```.subscribe(response => { console.log(response.headers); } )```?